# How can we cut mirror or glass in a desired shape?

Tags: material-selection, glass, cutting

How can we transform the glass in the desired shape or size. If we want to cut a glass which instrument should we use on domestic level.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I often use [mirrored vinyl film](https://www.amazon.com/Silver-Repositionable-Adhesive-Backed-Cutters-Punches/dp/B074JG6HC1/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1543768727&sr=8-3&keywords=mirror+vinyl) for odd shaped mirrors.  This doesn't really produce a real mirror surface (it is more like chrome) but it has solved a lot of problems for me and is very easy to cut to shape either with scissors or a vinyl cutter like silhouette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what sort of shape you're thinking of.

A convex polygon can be done with the [scribe and snap method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQaLV35HQEU) used for rectangles. This uses a [wheel glass cutter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-Heavy-Diamond-Glass-Cutter/dp/B01C543F8W/ref=lp_1938876031_1_4_sspa?s=diy&ie=UTF8&qid=1543828603&sr=1-4-spons&psc=1) or [diamond scriber](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KUNSE-Diamond-Carbide-Engraving-Lettering/dp/B07DVTMHXF/ref=sr_1_6?s=diy&ie=UTF8&qid=1543828643&sr=1-6&keywords=diamond+scriber%23) You should be all right up to an octagon at least, before the angles between the sides are too small.

Circles and large holes require a [special tool](https://www.wholesaleglasscompany.co.uk/acatalog/Glass-Circle-Cutters.html)

Small holes can be drilled and notches etc. can be cut using abrasive (diamond/silicon carbide/aluminium oxide) tools, usually wet, and usually slowly. These can be motorised (e.g. a Dremel or a drill) but hand tools are also available.  I've used a precision diamond saw to cut internal corners; this could probably be done using a cutoff wheel on a rotary tool.  Abrasives are also useful for rounding off corners and removing sharp edges (normal wet/dry SiC paper, a tile file, or a knife-sharpening stone)

[Grozing pliers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaker-grozier_pliers) combined with scoring are used for tricky shapes, but I'm told there's an art to using them.

---

Note: links are to examples so you know what I'm talking about.  I'm not recommending specific products or suppliers. In fact a local hardware shop should have the wheel glass cutter and abrasive drill bits/Dremel accessories.